# Trying to set up a subquery to compare an average price to all prices for a given category

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Using `Postgresql 12.2`

I am working on a table with columns for meal_id (specific meal instances), type (cuisine type), customer ids, meal prices, etc. There are 6 cuisine types (Italian, Japanese, etc). I need to find the average price for each type of cuisine, then display which specific meal_ids for each type have a higher price than the average price of that type.

When I try this:

```
select m1.*  
 from meals m1  
 join (select avg(price) 
       from meals  
       group by type) average  
 on meal_id=meal_id  
 where price > average  
 group by type;
```

I get the error message:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer > record LINE 7:  where price average

I'm not sure why I am getting this error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, avg(price) over (partition by type) as type_price
      from meals m
     ) m
where price > type_price;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And for introducing me to window functions :). Appreciate it.